# When is it better practice to explicitly use the delegate keyword instead of a lambda?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, delegates, lambda

Is there any best practice with respect to coding style with respect to explicit use of the `delegate` keyword instead of using a lambda?

e.g.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    // work item 1
    // work item 2
}).Start();

new Thread(delegate()
{
    // work item 1
    // work item 2
}).Start();
```

I think the lambda looks better. If the lambda is better style, what's the point of having a `delegate` keyword, other than for the fact that it existed before lambdas were implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda syntax is much more generalised, and the designers have said that they'd ideally remove the old overlapping syntaxes (dont have a citation, but it's probably Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet in a book or a podcast).

But `delegate` allows you to ignore parameters, e.g.:

```
object.Event += delegate { };
```

versus having to say:

```
object.Event += (sender,args) => { };
```

which can be very useful in large argument lists and/or to make the code more resilient to refactoring.

EDIT: As pointed out by [Yann Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23212/yann-schwartz) in another answer (now unfortunately deleted), a very neat usage of this trick is in order to provide a default hander for an event using the Null Object pattern:-

```
class MyClassThatFiresWithoutTheTrick
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent; // implicit = null

    // Need a method to keep this DRY as each fire requires a null check - see Framework Design Guidelines by Abrams and Cwalina
    protected virtual void OnMyEvent()
    {
        // need to take a copy to avoid race conditions with _removes
        // See CLR via C# 3rd edition p 264-5 for reason why this happens to work
        //var handler = MyEvent;
        // BUT THIS is the preferred version
        var handler = Interlocked.CompareExchange( ref MyEvent, null, null);
        // Need to do this check as it might not have been overridden
        if( handler == null)
            return;
        handler( this, EventArgs.Empty );
    }
}

class MyClassThatFiresWithTheTrick
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent = delegate{};

    protected virtual void OnMyEvent()
    {
        MyEvent( this, EventArgs.Empty );
    }
}
```

(though what you might often end up doing is an Inline Method of `OnMyEvent`, making the code even shorter again.)

Comment: I did not add this as a comment [I love your passive agressive way of stating it in an aside, btw] was because I actually answered before you did. Sorry for not having a time machine handy.

Comment: Well, to be exact, I hit submit while you were answering. HTH.

Comment: "Lambda syntax is much more generalised, and the designers have said that they'd ideally remove the old overlapping syntaxes (dont have a citation, but it's probably Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet in a book or a podcast)." - That's what I was looking for, cheers.

Comment: @Yann: I should be more mature and will remove all references to this nonsense. But if you look at the answers, mine was posted 2 mins before yours and didnt add much. When that happens to me, I delete my answer. My passive agressiveness was triggered by this, sorry.

Comment: @Yann: Before I delete the EDIT: section and fighting comments, can you please add a reference to the Null Object pattern into your answer and we can close this off? I'll even chuck in a +1 :P

Comment: @Yann: You were supposed to edit into your answer and me +1 it! If you're bothered, feel free to Extract Answer everything below the *EDIT:* marker.

Comment: @Yann No it's ok really. No need for duplicate answers since yours has it all now.

Comment: Well, *ideally* we would have gotten it perfect in C# 2, and not ended up with two syntaxes to do the same thing in C# 3. I personally never use the anonymous method ("delegate") syntax unless I'm writing code that has to be portable to C# 2.